# Как справить ошибку primordials is not defined?

Tags: gulp, npm

версия ноды v14.15.1
гальп
CLI version 2.1.0
Local version 3.9.1

запускаю гальп возникает ошибка

gulp development

```
fs.js:45
} = primordials;
^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:45:5
at req_ (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
at Object. (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
```

на 12 версии ноды

```
const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                         ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:26
    at req_ (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
```

вернул галь на 11 версию увидел новую ошибку
node -v
v11.14.0
gulp development

```
C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15
      throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
      ^

Error: Missing binding C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-67\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 11.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 14.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:166:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
```

Comment: ну тут явно конфликт между версиями ноды/гульпа и примордиала

Comment: установил гальп 3.9 и ноду v11.14.0 проект запустился ,но не доконца
`

Comment: >gulp development
[12:04:31] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\gulpfile.js
[12:04:31] Starting 'stylesheets'...
[12:04:31] Starting 'js'...
[12:04:31] Starting 'image'...
[12:04:31] Starting 'html'...
[12:04:31] Starting 'watch'...
[12:04:31] Finished 'watch' after 28 ms
[12:04:31] Starting 'server'...
[12:04:31] Finished 'server' after 19 ms

events.js:170
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: "java" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.`